# Установка локали в приложении

Tags: java, android, locale

пытаюсь сменить локаль в приложении:

```
private void setLocale(Locale locale){
        Resources resources = getResources();
        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){
            configuration.setLocale(locale);
            getApplicationContext().createConfigurationContext(configuration);
        }
        else{
            configuration.locale=locale;
            resources.updateConfiguration(configuration,displayMetrics);
        }
    }
```

при нажатии на кнопки:
public void onClick(View v) {

```
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.tbRus:{
            Locale locale = new Locale("ru");
            setLocale(locale);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "RUS");
            break;
        }
        case R.id.tbBe:{
            Locale locale = new Locale("be");
            setLocale(locale);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "BEL");
            break;
        }
        case R.id.tbUk:{
            Locale locale = new Locale("uk");
            setLocale(locale);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "UK");
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Но ничего не происходит, в чём моя ошибка?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прописал локализацию в editor'е для этих языков

Comment: Активити не пересоздаете? Изменения конфигурации не применятся без пересоздания активити. Предполагаю, что проблема в этом.

Comment: а как правильно пересоздать активити?

Comment: Проблема в вашем коде в том, что в случае API >= 17 вы создаете context, а дальше нигде его не используете. Есть отличная статья на этот счет: https://proandroiddev.com/change-language-programmatically-at-runtime-on-android-5e6bc15c758, а также тестовый пример на гитхабе, который показывает, как реализовывать переключение между языками: https://github.com/YarikSOffice/LanguageTest. Посмотрите, как сделано в этом примере.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Быстрофикс для вашего примера:

```java
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    configuration.setLocale(locale)
} else {
    configuration.locale = locale
}
resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, displayMetrics)
```

Проблема такого подхода в том, что метод `updateConfiguration()` будет удален в будущих версиях Андроид (в API 28 его ещё не удалили).

Если хотите сделать правильно, то смотрите как сделано в этом [примере на гитхабе](https://github.com/YarikSOffice/LanguageTest) (или в этом [посте](https://proandroiddev.com/change-language-programmatically-at-runtime-on-android-5e6bc15c758)).